# How do I return an array of chars?

Tags: c++, arrays, char

The program works properly if my function is `void`. But I have to return the value and there's a problem.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

char* fun(char arr[][100]);

int main() {
    char arr[5][100] = { "Saturn", "Venus","Mars", "Earth", "Neptun" };
    char *inscription = fun(arr);
    std::cout << inscription;
}

char* fun(char arr[][100]) {
    char longer[100];
    strcpy_s(longer, arr[0]);
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        if (strlen(arr[i]) > strlen(longer))
            strcpy_s(longer, arr[i]);
    }
    return longer;
}
```

I would be thankful for an answer.

Comment: Why not use `std::string`?

Comment: As this is C++ do not make things to complicated and just use `std::string` and `std::vector<std::string>`.

Comment: Why must you make a hard copy of the found data? Can't you just return a pointer to it?

Comment: Simply put the array in a struct and return that. Resp. use `std::array`. The byte copying code is then generated by the compiler, and you don't have stale pointers.

Comment: I assume using c strings instead of the proper c++ `std::string` is a requirement of an assignment.

Comment: @Vatnax I see that this question is still listed as unanswered (since you didn't accept one of the answers). If you don't understand something in an answer you can ask for clarification in the comment section under that answer and the author of the answer can edit it to make it better.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to return an array of chars from a function, I see two options:

- a) Create a heap allocated array of characters and return a pointer to it
- b) Give the function an array of chars to fill

a)

```
char* fun(char arr[][100]) {
    char* longer = new char[100];
    // ... do something
    return longer
}
```

b)

```
int main()
{
    //...
    char longer[100];
    fun(arr, longer);
    //...
}

void fun(char arr[][100], char* longer) {
    // ... fill longer
}
```

I think that best approach is the second one because you are not allocating anything on the heap and save yourself from dealing with unnecessary issues. You should avoid heap allocations when you can because they can cause issues if the caller doesn't free the memory and take time to do.

Comment: "I think that best approach is the second one" nope, best approach is to use `std::string` when you work with strings and return it by value

Comment: The best approach when use a raw array of chars

Answer (score 0):

Try to correct the function to be like that:

```
char* fun(char arr[][100]) {
    char *longer = new char[100];
    strcpy_s(longer, arr[0]);
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        if (strlen(arr[i]) > strlen(longer))
            strcpy_s(longer, arr[i]);
    }
    return longer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you create a local variable and then return a pointer to it, but when the function is finished the variable is destroyed so the pointer becomes invalid. You operates further with the invalid pointer, BOOM. The simplest way to deal with it -- use class-function.

```
/* main.cpp */

#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

struct Func
 {
  char longer[100];

  explicit Func(char arr[][100])
   {
    strcpy(longer, arr[0]);

    for (int i = 1; i < 5; ++i) {
        if (strlen(arr[i]) > strlen(longer))
            strcpy(longer, arr[i]);
    }
   }

  const char * result() const { return longer; }
 };

int main() {
    char arr[5][100] = { "Saturn", "Venus","Mars", "Earth", "Neptun" };

    Func fun(arr);

    cout << fun.result() << endl ;

    return 0;
}
```

There are some other problems with this code, but I leave it here as is.

Answer (score 0):

For starters you have to define the function correctly. It shall have a second parameter that will specify the number of elements in the passed array.

It can look at least the following way

```
char * fun( char arr[][100] , size_t n ) 
{
    char *longer = arr[0];

    for ( size_t i = 1; i < n; ++i ) 
    {
        if ( std::strlen(longer) < std::strlen( arr[i] ) )
        {
            longer = arr[i];
        }
    }

    return longer;
}
```

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

const size_t N = 100;

const char * fun( const char arr[][N] , size_t n ) 
{
    const char *longer = arr[0];

    for ( size_t i = 1; i < n; ++i ) 
    {
        if ( std::strlen(longer) < std::strlen( arr[i] ) )
        {
            longer = arr[i];
        }
    }

    return longer;
}

int main() 
{
    char arr[][N] = 
    { 
        "Saturn", "Venus","Mars", "Earth", "Neptun" 
    };

    const size_t M = sizeof( arr ) / sizeof( *arr );

    const char *inscription = fun( arr , M );

    std::cout << inscription << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
Saturn
```

However the function has a drawback. For example in general the user can pass as the second argument the value `0`. Dereferencing the passed pointer as the first argument in this case can result in undefined behavior. Moreover the function `strlen` is called a redundant number of times.

Here is a more safe function implementation.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

const size_t N = 100;

const char ( * fun( const char arr[][N] , size_t n ) )[N] 
{
    const char ( *longer )[N] = arr;
    size_t longer_len = 0;

    if ( n != 0 )
    {
        longer_len = std::strlen( *longer );
    }

    for ( size_t i = 1; i < n; ++i ) 
    {
        size_t len = std::strlen( arr[i] );

        if ( longer_len < len )
        {
            longer = arr + i;
            longer_len = len;
        }
    }

    return longer;
}

int main() 
{
    char arr[][N] = 
    { 
        "Saturn", "Venus","Mars", "Earth", "Neptun" 
    };

    const size_t M = sizeof( arr ) / sizeof( *arr );

    auto inscription = fun( arr , M );

    std::cout << *inscription << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
Saturn
```

If declarations used in the function looks complicated then you can simplify them using the specifier `auto`. For example

```
auto fun( const char arr[][N] , size_t n ) 
{
    auto longer = arr;
    size_t longer_len = 0;

    if ( n != 0 )
    {
        longer_len = std::strlen( *longer );
    }

    for ( size_t i = 1; i < n; ++i ) 
    {
        size_t len = std::strlen( arr[i] );

        if ( longer_len < len )
        {
            longer = arr + i;
            longer_len = len;
        }
    }

    return longer;
}
```

Also if you want that the function would not depend on the size elements of the two-dimensional array you can declare the function as a template function.
Here you are.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

template <size_t N>
auto fun( const char arr[][N] , size_t n ) 
{
    auto longer = arr;
    size_t longer_len = 0;

    if ( n != 0 )
    {
        longer_len = std::strlen( *longer );
    }

    for ( size_t i = 1; i < n; ++i ) 
    {
        size_t len = std::strlen( arr[i] );

        if ( longer_len < len )
        {
            longer = arr + i;
            longer_len = len;
        }
    }

    return longer;
}

int main() 
{
    const size_t N = 100;
    char arr[][N] = 
    { 
        "Saturn", "Venus","Mars", "Earth", "Neptun" 
    };

    const size_t M = sizeof( arr ) / sizeof( *arr );

    auto inscription = fun( arr , M );

    std::cout << *inscription << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

An alternative approach of implementation such a function is when the function returns the index of the target element instead of a pointer to it.

For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

template <size_t N>
size_t fun( const char arr[][N] , size_t n ) 
{
    size_t longer = 0;
    size_t longer_len = 0;

    if ( n != 0 )
    {
        longer_len = std::strlen( arr[longer] );
    }

    for ( size_t i = 1; i < n; ++i ) 
    {
        size_t len = std::strlen( arr[i] );

        if ( longer_len < len )
        {
            longer = i;
            longer_len = len;
        }
    }

    return longer;
}

int main() 
{
    const size_t N = 100;
    char arr[][N] = 
    { 
        "Saturn", "Venus","Mars", "Earth", "Neptun" 
    };

    const size_t M = sizeof( arr ) / sizeof( *arr );

    size_t inscription = fun( arr , M );

    std::cout << arr[inscription] << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

But as the program is a C++ program then actually you need not to write your own function. You could use the standard algorithm `std::max_element` declared in the header `<algorithm>` with a corresponding lambda expression like

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

const size_t N = 100;


int main() 
{
    char arr[][N] = 
    { 
        "Saturn", "Venus","Mars", "Earth", "Neptun" 
    };

    auto inscription = std::max_element( std::begin( arr ), std::end( arr ),
                                         []( const auto &s1, const auto &s2 )
                                         {
                                            return std::strlen( s1 ) < std::strlen( s2 );
                                         } );

    std::cout << *inscription << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is the same as shown above

```
Saturn
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend returning a pointer into the original array instead of copying.
Here's an alternative passing the array by reference instead of by value (which is expensive).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

// make it a function template to accept arrays of different sizes
template<size_t N, size_t L>
char* fun(char (&arr)[N][L]) {                 // pass by reference
    char* longest = arr[0];                    // make a pointer to the first
    size_t longest_len = std::strlen(longest); // and store its length

    for(size_t i = 1; i < N; ++i) {
        // check if a longer C string is found
        if(size_t alen = strlen(arr[i]); alen > longest_len) {
            // store the new length and a pointer to the new C string
            longest_len = alen;
            longest = arr[i];
        }
    }
    return longest; // return pointer into the original array
}

int main() {
    char arr[][100] = { "Saturn", "Venus","Mars", "Earth", "Neptun" };
    char *inscription = fun(arr);
    std::cout << inscription << '\n';     // Saturn
}
```

This would however be easier and less error prone using `std::vector` and `std::string`.